# How to keep the intervals in the chart? In Designer the necessary code lines keeps disappearing

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, scrollbar

What I work with: C#, Windows Forms, Visual Studio 2017

I'm trying to get a chart which would show some statistics after selecting a period (for this I have two datetimepickers). And in the chart's X-axis it doesn't show all the values it should, only several values as can be seen in screenshot below. And the Y-axis doesn't even show any values.

(alas, I don't have 10 points of reputation to post images, so I provide the links to images)

**First screenshot**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYq4b.png?

In stackoverflow I found some solutions:

```
chartCheck.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = Your type here;
chartCheck.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
chart.ChartAreas["chart1"].AxisX.Interval = 10;
```

Based on these, I wrote code for X- and Y-axis intervals and put them into the designer file, but they keep disappearing:

```
chartIncHalfHoursPerPerson.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chartIncHalfHoursPerPerson.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;
```

Here's how the part of code looks like in Designer:

```
chartArea2.AxisY.Title = "Incompliant Half-Hours";
chartArea2.Name = "ChartArea1";
this.chartIncHalfHoursPerPerson.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea2);
chartIncHalfHoursPerPerson.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chartIncHalfHoursPerPerson.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;
```

With this I can get the X- and Y-axis to show all the values I want, as can be seen in the screenshot below (in the link).

**Second screenshot**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjdCV.png?

**The problem** is that this part of code (see below) disappears after some time (or probably after 1-2 program runs, I couldn't figure the moment and reason of their disappearance) and it all goes back to how it was in the first schreenshot (with much less values being shown):

```
chartIncHalfHoursPerPerson.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chartIncHalfHoursPerPerson.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;
```

I probably should add some more info:

0) about the program I'm doing

1) about the fact that in other forms similar lines of code do not disappear - they just stay there firmly

2) about my assumptions about what might be a cause to the <strike>mysterious</strike> disappearance of the code

**Part 0:**
It's a program that shows some statistics by request in 4 forms. Three of these forms have one chart, while the 4th form has 2 charts.

**Part 1:**
As stated above, there are 3 other forms each with one chart. They all have a part of code similar to what is in the form with 2 charts (see code and a link with screenshot below).

```
chartIncHalfHoursPerPerson.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chartIncHalfHoursPerPerson.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;
```

**Third screenshot**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd74T.png?

**Part 2:**
So here's what I think may be the cause:

0) Each chart is connected to the corresponding BindingSource. If it's a form with one chart - it works pretty much OK. But in our case we have 2 charts and each of them is connected to the same BindingSource.

1) The simple fact there are 2 charts in one form?

2) The layout of this form is basically several SplitContainers which were put one above another. In total, 4 SplitContainers. I'm not sure if it's a bad or normal way to set a "foundation" in a form.

3) I tried both Dock (with "Fill") and Anchor (with "Top, Left, Right, Bottom"). Well, Dock works better, but still doesn't solve the problem.

4) Maybe, I shouldn't be adding the code in Designer, but rather in the file where the form's logic opeartions are written.

5) Finally, I wondered if the problem is due to absence of horizontal scrollbar. After all, there are too much surnames on X-axis. I tried to look into properties of SplitContaner and Chart, then googled about how to add a scrollbar. Tried this code, but the scrollbar doesn't even appear:

```
chartIncHalfHoursPerPerson.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
chartIncHalfHoursPerPerson.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;
chartIncHalfHoursPerPerson.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Size = 10;
chartIncHalfHoursPerPerson.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll;
chartIncHalfHoursPerPerson.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
chartIncHalfHoursPerPerson.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
```

Well, most of googled websites tell about how to add a scrollbar to the chart (in the chart itself, not under chart and legends)

Comment: _Maybe, I shouldn't be adding the code in Designer_ At least not in the parts that tell you to __not edit__ them.

Answer (score 1):

some parts of winform code are auto generated. There are comments in the files, search for: -

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code

Any editing you do in these regions will disappear.